# Select em duas tabelas com cláusula WHERE?

Tags: mysql, select

Preciso verificar se um determinado e-mail existe em duas tabelas, se o mesmo existir em um das duas tabelas o usuário não poderá se registrar, facilitando seria o código abaixo, a coluna email é presente nas duas tabelas;

```
SELECT * FROM tab1, tab2 WHERE email = :email
```

Já tentei

```
SELECT 
    usuarios.email, usr_pend.email
FROM usuarios, usr_pend 
    WHERE usuarios.email = :email
    OR usr_pend.email = :email
```

E também tentei

```
SELECT 
    usr.*, pen.* 
FROM usuarios usr 
    INNER JOIN usr_pend pen 
        ON usr.email = :email
        OR pen.email = :email
```

Mas ambas as formas retornam 0, quando na verdade o email está presente em uma delas, como eu deveria fazer essa verificação?

Comment: Consegui entender as respostas lá, já alterei e coloquei aqui, funcionou perfeitamente, mas obrigado mesmo assim ^

Comment: De qualquer forma, editei a resposta simplificando pra servir em casos mais simples, se quiser dar uma olhada. Assim fica como solução geral :)

Comment: Opa, obrigado por simplificar, ficou mais fácil entender o que acontece quando usamos o UNION, novamente muito obrigado ;)